# error in bitbucket-pipelines.yml at [pipelines > step > condition]. To be precise: At least one condition is required

Tags: yaml, bitbucket, pipeline, cicd, dbt

I created a bitbucket pipelines that looks like this:

```
pipelines:
  custom: 
    dbt-run:
      - step:
          name: 'Validate'
          script:
            - cd dbt_4flow
            - dbt compile
          condition:
            changesets:
            includePaths:
             - "dbt_4flow/*"
```

However, when I try to run it via the UI, I get this error even though I have already given a condition. What am I doing wrong? Is it the syntax?

```
There is an error in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml at [pipelines > custom > dbt-run > 0 > step > condition]. To be precise: At least one condition is required
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be an indentation issue. The following indentation should work.

```yaml
pipelines:
  custom: 
    dbt-run:
      - step:
          name: 'Validate'
          script:
            - cd dbt_4flow
            - dbt compile
          condition:
            changesets:
              includePaths:
                - "dbt_4flow/*"
```